# str_getcsv gives wrong separations with Japanese

Tags: php, arrays, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to parse csv data to arrays with str_getcsv in PHP but the separation of the data will be changed in the arrays.

my locale setting

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');
```

my original csv data

```
"タナカ","タロウ"
```

data given by str_getcsv

```
"タナカ",タロウ""
```

and it's also combine as a value.
It seems like katakana is causing the problem but I'm not sure.
I tried either csv with or without BOM. But It didn't make nay difference.

If you have any ideas to solve this problem please share with me.
Thank you.

Comment: Appears to work fine if the input data is actually UTF-8, https://3v4l.org/mFmKg

Comment: Please post a reproducible example like it @CBroe did it. If the string looks like the example, the comma is not used as a separator. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96aec500e22ab188171ae50c5d79055090d88fab